# How should I localize system strings that always have to be in english in the database?

Tags: java, localization

We are localizing our product and I've hit a bit of a stumbling block. Our server is not being localized and therefore the database (it polls the db) needs to remain in english. Our client is being localized. The question is, for system strings (strings that the server expects to always be in english) how/when do we do the lookup/conversion before updating the db?

For example, we have a string, READY. This string will be displayed in the client in a different language. If a user selects this string we have to convert it back to READY before we update the db. Really there are 2 conversions, when the client reads the db it's in english as READY so it needs to convert it to the current locale, then when the user selects that value it needs to convert it back to the english READY. What is the best way to implement these conversions?

Note: we are using the usual java properties files for our localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store an index on the control that always refers to (or contains) the untranslated string, so that you can use that instead even once the displayed text has been l10n'ed.

Comment: This is the route I'm trying first, but it seems so brute force. I was hoping there would be another way.